# Accessing JSON element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON as given below and wanted to access city element in my angularjs. I am trying `record1.vendorInfo.addresses.city` but it is not working here `record1` is JSON data returned from `$http.get`.

```
{  
  "vendorId":"9818111362",
  "vendorInfo":{  
    "addresses":[  
      {  
        "id":1,
        "city":"Delhi",
        "locality":"Mayur Vihar Phase 1",
        "latitude":1123.4,
        "longitude":2234.5,
        "detailAddress":"Flat No. 199, gali no 6, pandav nagar",
        "addressType":"HOME"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you write in bold ? we are not blind. And show the js code when it fails.

Comment: Could you show us where do you call this variable ?

Comment: I am not blind and I did nothing special to make it bold .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addresses is an Array,you should access city by `rec.vernderinfo.addresses[0].city`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create object from JSON. E.g. `var rec = angular.fromJson(record1)`. Then it would be possible to navigate through properties: `rec.vendorInfo.addresses.city`.

Comment: Here is how my code looks like:. Please suggest .
    RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('record1.json')
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("Error occurred. Status: " + response.status + " - " +  response.statusText);
    });
    }]);

    RecordApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'recordaccess',     function($scope, recordaccess) {
    recordaccess.then(function(data) {
    $scope.record1 = data;
    });
    }]);